# Different JSON format is being returned depending on the number of JSON objects returned

Tags: javascript, json

I have note what seems to be an error in a product API . the problem is a follow:-
1. if the returned JSON contains more than one process (two processes in my case)  then the JSON result will be  as follow:-

```
{"total":2,"data":[{"id":"leaveApp#2#leaveApplicationProcess","packageName":"Leave App","name":"Leave Application Process","packageId":"leaveApp","label":"Leave Application Process ver 2","version":"2"},{"id":"leaveApp#2#process1","packageName":"Leave App","name":"Leave Application Process2","packageId":"leaveApp","label":"Leave Application Process2 ver 2","version":"2"}]}
```

and i am being able to display the two processes using the following javaScript:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=admin&packageId=leaveApp",

        dataType: "JSONP",

        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
                var str = val.name + ' | Version ' + val.version;
                                $('<li/>', { text: str })
                .appendTo($('#products'));

            });        }
    }); });
```

While if the packageid contain only one process then the above Java script will return `"undefined"` for the JSON, since i think because there will be no data property and the returned JSON format will be as follow:-

```
{"total":1,"data":{"id":"crm#1#process1","packageName":"CRM","name":"Proposal Approval Process","packageId":"crm","label":"Proposal Approval Process ver 1","version":"1"}}.
```

So can anyone help me on how i can make my javascruipt works regardless of the number of processes OR this is a problem in the API itself?

Best Regards

**Update**

```
I modify my JavaScript to be as follow:-
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
       // url: "http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=admin&packageId=" + 'name',
        url: fullurl,
        dataType: "JSONP",
        // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            var arr = ( (typeof(result.data) == 'object')        && 
                        (result.data.constructor.name == 'Array') )
                 ? result.data
                 : [result.data];
            $.each(arr, function (key, val) {


                // Format the text to display.
                //   var str = val.packageName + ' | ' + val.packageId;
                var str = val.name + ' | Version ' + val.version;
                // Add a list item for the product.
                $('<li/>', { text: str })
                .appendTo($('#products'));

            });
        }
    });
```

But currently if there are more then one JSON object it will return "undefined", while if there are only One JSOn object then it will work fine ... so my original problem is now Vice Versa .

Answer (score 0):

That's because the JSON data isn't in a consistent format. To fix it, you could always make `data` return as an Array, whether or not there are multiple processes (elements of the array).

Alternatively, try this:

```
var arr = ( (typeof(result.data) == 'object')        && 
            (result.data.constructor.name == 'Array') )
     ? result.data
     : [result.data];
$.each(arr, function (key, val) {
   // ... rest goes here
});
```

**edit:** fixed typo in `object`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, then can i consider the "JSON data isn't in a consistent format" as a problem in the Web service i am calling ? OR it is a problem with my own JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, definitely - it's a problem in the web-service! (Sometimes `data` is a JSON Array, other times it's a  JSON Object). That's usually because they've naively translated XML to JSON.

Comment: see my update , Your code will work only if there is one JSON object exists

Comment: Then your original supposition about what is returned in the JSON is incorrect. Could you post both types of response *exactly* as returned in each case?

Comment: thanks , i already provided the two JSON returned in my original post.